Baby Rudin Theorem 1.19 Step 3
I am following Baby Rudin's Analysis and reading Theorem 1.19 Step 3. This is to prove that the ordered set $\mathbb{R}$ has the least upper bound property. So, $A$ is taken as a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Also its assumed that $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ is an upper bound of $A$. And $\gamma$ is defined to be the union of all $\alpha \in A$. The author goes on to prove that $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\gamma = \sup A$. Next, following statements appear.
Since $A$ is not empty, there exists an $\alpha_0 \in A$. This $\alpha_0$ is not empty. Since $\alpha_0 \subset \gamma$, $\gamma$ is not empty. Next, $\gamma \subset \beta$ (since $\alpha \subset \beta$ for every $\alpha \in A$), and therefore $\gamma \ne \mathbb{Q}$.
Now, I have understood everything except $\gamma \ne \mathbb{Q}$. How does this follow ?

Without checking Rudin's book, this should follow from $\gamma\subset\beta$ and $\beta\neq\mathbb Q$.

Since $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, which means that $\beta$ itself is a cut and hence $\beta \ne \mathbb{Q}$ (first property of a cut). Since $\gamma \subset \beta$, it follows that $\gamma \ne \mathbb{Q}$. Thanks.
